# How an I pass an array that is obtained within ngOnInti() to a graph that is outside of that function?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

**Objective:**

My objective is to crate a graph from data that is pulled in via an API and call and then reformed. The call happens within ngOnInit(), and the graphing happens external to it. I cannot get the data that is pulled in, pushed into the graph:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {StockServicesComponent} from '../services/stock-services.component';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import { Options } from 'highcharts/highstock';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-high-charts',
  templateUrl: './high-charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./high-charts.component.css']
})
export class HighChartsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
               private service: StockServicesComponent) { }

  stockPrices = [];
  dates = [];
  prices = [];
  newDataset = [];

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        data : this.newDataset
      }
    ]
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const tickerId = params.tickerId;
      this.service.findCompanyPriceHistory(tickerId)
        .then(stockPrices => this.stockPrices = stockPrices);
      console.log('Reached Highcharts 1: ', this.newDataset);

      this.stockPrices.forEach(obj => {
        const tmp = [];
        tmp.push(obj.updated);
        tmp.push(obj.close);
        this.newDataset.push(tmp);
        console.log('----------------');
      });
      console.log('Reached Highcharts 2: ', this.newDataset);
    });
  }
}
```

**The Question:**

How do I feed "newDataset" to the graph as specified with "data : this.newDataset"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following implementation where data update is performed within a dedicated function  which, in turn, is triggered once data has been resolved (within `.then`):

```
public updateDataSet(stockPrices: any[]):void {
  stockPrices.forEach(obj => {
    const tmp = [];
    tmp.push(obj.updated);
    tmp.push(obj.close);
    this.newDataset.push(tmp);
  });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.service
      .findCompanyPriceHistory(params.tickerId)
      .then(stockPrices => this.updateDataSet(stockPrices));
  });
}
```

Or even more concisely:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params
    .pipe(
      switchMap(x => this.service.findCompanyPriceHistory(x.tickerId))
    )
    .subscribe(stockPrices => this.updateDataSet(stockPrices));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the demo below you might find an example of how to handle the data from external service. 
It's a simple local solution, but it might show you the way.

```
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Options;

  constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          type: "line",
          data: dataService.getData()
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-service-2